# register_post_type - rewrite / feeds, what's it for?

Tags: custom-post-types, feed

The [codex page for register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) seems to suggest that it should be possible to disable feed generation for custom post types:

```
 rewrite
    (boolean or array) (optional) Triggers the handling of rewrites for this post type. 
    To prevent rewrites, set to false.
...

$args array
...
    'feeds' => bool Should a feed permalink structure be built for this post type. 
        Defaults to has_archive value.
```

I read that as meaning this:

```
 register_post_type('People', array('rewrite' => array('feeds' => false)));
```

would result in my 'People' archive page *not* having this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Site &raquo; People Feed"
    href="http://mysite.com/people/feed/" />
```

in its head. However, the above is output in the HTML. Have I misunderstood, or done something wrong? I do not want a feed to be generated.

Any help much appreciated.

Toby

Comment: Maybe the feed link is hardcoded in the header template of your current theme.

Comment: It's not unfortunately, it's coming out of wp_head()

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone...

I had misunderstood - the feeds argument of 'rewrite' was merely about the formatting of feed URLs (to use rewriting).

What I want is *not* to have a feed URL output in the `<head>` of my custom post type pages. The only way I have found to do this, is using

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
```

although this will suppress the feed in other circumstances (categories etc), not just for my custom post type. If anyone knows how to do what I want I'd love to hear from you!

Toby